# Bootstrap tooltips and popovers: To Destroy, or NOT To Destroy?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, popover

if I create tooltips and popovers via BS' tooltip() and popover() methods, is there a need to do any explicit destroying of said creations if the DOM changes and the affected elements are no longer present? Am I creating JS dust bunnies by NOT explicitly destroying?

Comment: The functionality provides the destroy function: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popover-destroy so it might be worth using it, just to be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to put toolips on dynamic content you should use a delegate as such:`$('body').toolip({selector: '.has-tooltip'});` and in this case, destroying is not needed.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4215

http://jsbin.com/zopod/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Oski/5gura2oq/

JS:

```
$(function () {
  var element = $('#example').popover();
  element.popover('show');
  element.remove();
});
```

Template:

```
<p>Click on button to see Popover</p>
<a href="#" id="example" class="btn btn-primary" rel="popover"
  data-content="This is the body of Popover"
  data-original-title="Creativity Tuts">pop
</a>
```

You can remove the anchor element and still have the popover visible, so I think you need to destroy your popover.

Answer (score 0):

Hello,

No need to destroy, when you close the popover or the tooltip automatically it is excluded from the DOM.

Here is an tooltip example:

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsbCR.png)

In this example I use jquery ui tooltip.

I hope I have helped!